# Error accessing media devices:Error Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser. Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I'm facing an issue while implementing WebRTC functionality in my application's local development environment. I'm using self-signed certificates but continuously encountering a 'Secure random number generation' error in WebRTC.

The specific error message I'm encountering is: "Error accessing media devices: Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser. Use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 11."

Here's a high-level overview of what I've attempted:

- Implemented self-signed certificates for local development purposes.
- Configured my server and client to communicate using these certificates.
- Updated dependencies and libraries, including simple-peer, socket.io-client, etc., to their latest versions.
- Ensured compatibility with commonly supported browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, preventing successful access to media devices, and resulting in the aforementioned error message.

Could there be specific configurations or settings required for WebRTC to function correctly with self-signed certificates in a local development environment? Are there any known workarounds or additional steps necessary to address the 'Secure random number generation' error in WebRTC?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

```js
const startMedia = async () => {
  try {
    const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    if (videoRef.current) {
      setStream(mediaStream);
      socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));
      videoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
    }
    if (socket) {
      const peer = new SimplePeer({
        initiator: true,
        trickle: false,
        stream: mediaStream,
      });

      peer.on('signal', (data) => {
        console.log('Sending signal to the peer:', data);
        socket.emit('signal', data);
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
  }
};
```